# Parse/read decoded jwt token data in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, jwt

How to  parse the below object which is an decoded jwt token using this.jwtHelper.decodeToken(sessionStorage.getItem('encodedToken')) and need to get the privileges of an application(QWE) from roles.

```
name:"ram8"
roles:"{"userid":"991635","privileges":{"QWE":["QQT","RR","RRR","FCC","WWW","WRD","DML","UDE","SDE"]}}"
sub:"123456"
user.tenant.name:"DefaultDomain"
__proto__:Object
```

Right now, using the below code to get the roles

```
public getUserRoles(){
    let userInfoJSON = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.jwtHelper.decodeToken(sessionStorage.getItem('encodedToken'))));
    for (let prop in userInfoJSON) {
        if(prop === 'roles'){
            let roles = JSON.parse(userInfoJSON[prop]);
            for(let rProp in roles){
                if(rProp === 'privileges'){
                    let privileges = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(roles[rProp]));
                    for(let prev in privileges){
                        console.log("prev "+prev+" "+privileges[prev])
                        this.userRoles = privileges[prev];
                    }
                }   
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    console.log("AuthServiceuserRoles "+this.userRoles);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`JSON.parse` parses the entire token, also nested objects.

You don't need the for-loops, you can just use `let roles = userInfoJSON.roles` and `let privileges = roles.privileges` etc

This is some example code I use to see if a user has a specific role:

```
let token = localStorage.getItem(jwtTokenName);
    if (token && tokenNotExpired(null, token)) {
        let tokenDecoded = jwtHelper.decodeToken(token);
        if (tokenDecoded.roles && tokenDecoded.roles.length > 0) {
            for (let i = 0; i < tokenDecoded.roles.length; i++) {
                const role = tokenDecoded.roles[i];
                if (roles.indexOf(role) >= 0) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```